# Dynamic Selenium Grid: SessionNotCreatedException -> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

We are running our e2e tests on a dynamic selenium grid which is provided by docker-compose on a virtual linux machine.

I am using:

1x selenium/hub:4.8.3

3 x selenium/node-docker:4.8.3

The configuration for the nodes is provided via a config.toml:

```
[docker]
configs = ["selenium/standalone-chrome:111.0-20230404", "{\"browserName\": \"chrome\", \"browserVersion\": \"111.0\"}"]
```

In Java i create the RemoteWebDriver with some configuration. The Arguments you see are stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t).

```
((ChromeOptions) caps)
        .setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs)
        .addArguments("--window-size=" + 1920 + "," + 1080)
        .addArguments("disable-infobars")
        .addArguments("--disable-extensions")
        .addArguments("--disable-gpu")
        .addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        .addArguments("--no-sandbox")
        .setCapability("se:recordVideo", true);


caps.merge(desiredCapabilities);

RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(webdriverProperties.getGridUrl()), caps);

remoteWebDriver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
remoteWebDriver.manage().window().maximize();

remoteWebDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

return remoteWebDriver;
```

The Exception i get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Could not start a new session. Could not start a new session. Unable to create session: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```